# Is there a way to force RSpec to re-evaluate a let statement?

Tags: ruby, rspec, tdd, bdd

This example is a bit contrived, but explains the use case well.

```
let( :number_of_users ){ User.count }

it 'counts users' do
  User.create
  number_of_users.should == 1
  User.create
  number_of_users.should == 2
end
```

This test fails because `number_of_users` is only evaluated once, and gets stale. Is there a way to have this re-evaluated each time it is called?

Comment: `let()` declerations are evaluated the first time they are called. `number_of_users` should be a function, as this is the behaviour you want.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can just define a regular method:

```
def number_of_users
  User.count
end

it 'counts users' do
  User.create
  number_of_users.should == 1
  User.create
  number_of_users.should == 2
end
```

See this [blog post](http://testdrivenwebsites.com/2011/08/17/different-ways-of-code-reuse-in-rspec/) for some more details, including how to store the helper methods in a separate module.

Comment: That blog post link is pretty useful.

Comment: I didn't implement this solution, but it seems to be the best so far...thanks.

Comment: The blog post link is now dead. Does anyone have an updated link?

Comment: The official RSpec documentation includes examples of not only how to store helper methods in a separate module, but also how to conditionally include them in specific groups. https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/v/3-10/docs/helper-methods/define-helper-methods-in-a-module

Answer (score 4):

How about writing such test like this:

```
it "counts user" do
  expect {
    User.create
  }.to change(User, :count).by(1)
end
```

Comment: Yes, that would be better for this test. But this is a simplified example to explain what I want to do. The real tests would be ***less*** readable in this form.

Comment: Provide real test and see if we can improve it.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer "no" (AFAIK)

If your method or object has a useful container though, you might gain something by assigning a variable to that.

Even more contrived than your example:

```
let( :user_module ){ User }

it 'counts users' do
  User.create
  user_module.count.should == 1
  User.create
  user_module.count.should == 2
end
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use proc

```
let( :number_of_users ){ proc { User.count } }

it 'counts users' do
  User.create
  number_of_users.call.should == 1
  User.create
  number_of_users.call.should == 2
end
```

Comment: thanks this was useful in a change block inside a shared example, even if I use a `let!` block it caches the output, but the proc solution works fine, thanks